# C# не работает Folder Browser Dialog [cefsharp - winforms]

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp

Не отображается окно выбора папки.
При нажатии на кнопку из JavaScript в C# отправляю строку "folder" и выполняю следующий код:

```
    case "folder":

                foreach (Form f in Application.OpenForms)
                {
                    if (f.GetType() == typeof(window))
                    {
                        window fTemp = (window)f;
                        fTemp.GetFolderPath();
                    }
                }

                break;
```

Функция GetFolderPath в классе формы:

```
    public string GetFolderPath()
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog folderBrowser = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        
        if (folderBrowser.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            return folderBrowser.SelectedPath;
        
        return "";
    }
```

Как мне отобразить окно выбора папки корректно?
Вызывать данный код целиком из класса с получением ответов из JavaScript пробовал, результат тот же.

Comment: Winforms, WPF, UWP?

Comment: WinForms, но думаю разницы не имеет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте открытие диалога перенаправить UI поток.

```csharp
public string GetFolderPath()
{
    FolderBrowserDialog folderBrowser = new FolderBrowserDialog();
    DialogResult result = DialogResult.Cancel;
    this.Invoke((Action)(() => result = folderBrowser.ShowDialog()));
    return result == DialogResult.OK ? folderBrowser.SelectedPath : "";
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Данное решение работает, в итоге код получился таким:

public void GetFolderPath()
        {
            this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                FolderBrowserDialog folderBrowser = new FolderBrowserDialog();

                if (folderBrowser.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {

                }
            }
            ));
        }

Comment: @waparabka поэтому Winforms или WPF - важно, решения разные. В таком случае можете поставить галочку слева от ответа.

Comment: Хорошо, учту. Галочку поставлю, пишет что возможно через 4 минуты.